# add labels to an array in plotly scatter plots

Tags: python, arrays, plot, plotly, data-visualization

Hi am working with an array ndarray with shape (5,250) and using plotly to plot the graph. [image: Scatter plot using plotly of my array]

This is the code I used to generate the plot.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(array_name, length_of_array)
fig.show()
```

I want to know how I can change the labels for the x and y axis. All the documentation I looked at had a proper dataset where one can specify one column name for the axis labels. In my case I just have an array.

Also I would like to make this interactive, like add relative pictures to the specific points, as I have folders for each point from where I can get the pics- Eg: /content/1/1.png.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='New X', yaxis_title='New Y')` [documentation examples](https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/)

Comment: For adding images to points look at [hover events](https://plotly.com/python/v3/cars-exploration/)